Integral of Theta function
I'm trying to compute the following integral, useful to calculate Amplitudes in String theory 
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d^2z}{\tau_2} \;\partial^2_z \log \vartheta_1\left(z\right) = - \frac{\pi}{\tau_2}
\end{equation}
(see for example Kiritsis notes, in the Appendix) but I can't reproduce the result. The way I'm doing it is as follows
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{dz d\bar{z}}{\tau_2} \; \partial^2_z \log \vartheta_1\left(z\right) = \oint \frac{d \bar{z}}{\tau_2} \; \partial_z \log \vartheta_1\left(z\right) = \oint \frac{d \bar{z}}{\tau_2} \;\frac{1}{z}
\end{equation}
Computing this integral however, for example setting $z = re^{i \theta}, \; 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, I get a vanishing result. Where am I wrong ? Thanks !

Link? Which page? Which eq?

@Qmechanic, look at the notes by Kiritsis, "Introduction to Superstring Theory", in Appendix equation A.34
